# How to Fire Command Event in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, mvvm-light

I am using silverlight4 mvvmlight.
I want to fire command event from the Datagrid.
My code for DataGrid is:

```
  <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleInProcessSource.View, Mode= TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentActivity, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" Binding="{Binding Path=Start}"/>

                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Binding="{Binding Path=Subject}"/>

                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="StoreName" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.OutletName}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="AddressLine1" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Address.AddressLine1}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="AddressLine2" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Address.AddressLine2}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="OwnerName" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.OwnerName}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ContactName" Binding="{Binding Path=Contact.FirstName}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="PhoneNo" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Phone}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="MobileNo" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Mobile}"/>

                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Resume" Command="{Binding ResumeAuditing}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

But the command doesn't work. How could I overcome the situation?
Please Help me out..

Comment: are you want to fire event from button inside datagrid?

Comment: Yes I want to fire command event of hyperlinkbutton I set Command={Binding...} but it doesn't work. Do you have any solution? Please help me out form this.

Comment: go through [http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=608519] one might help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using silverlight so there is no LinkButton.

Comment: ohh.. Then this will help you sure[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396203/how-to-fire-event-from-button-inside-datagrid-in-silverlight-and-mvvm]

Comment: I tried this but doesnt work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

```
  <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleInProcessSource.View, Mode= TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentActivity, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgInProcess">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" Binding="{Binding Path=Start}"/>

                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Binding="{Binding Path=Subject}"/>

                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="StoreName" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.OutletName}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="AddressLine1" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Address.AddressLine1}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="AddressLine2" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Address.AddressLine2}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="OwnerName" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.OwnerName}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ContactName" Binding="{Binding Path=Contact.FirstName}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="PhoneNo" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Phone}"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="MobileNo" Binding="{Binding Path=Outlet.Mobile}"/>

                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Resume">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Path=ScheduleViewModel.ResumeAuditing}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </HyperlinkButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Delete">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Path=ScheduleViewModel.DeleteCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>


                            </HyperlinkButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

This will work..